# Lattice structures, Metallic Bonding

Tags: bond, crystal-structure, metal

How and under what circumstances can cations form a lattice structure?
Would they not repel each other?

Comment: Cations _alone_ can never form a lattice structure. As you correctly pointed out, they would repel each other.

Comment: Is this a problem with metallic bonding, or what?

Comment: Thanks, They are surrounded by localized electrons as per what i found  out.Yes it is a problem with metallic bonding